# Adding form and paypal to a website

Tags: forms, paypal

I have made a website using bootstrap and now I want to add a form with a pay-with-Paypal button, which will redirect the user to Paypal for payment and send me the data filled in the form. How am I supposed to do it. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I have already purchased a hosting which support php, mysql etc

Answer (score 0):

For the buttons themselves, you have [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_singleitem-intro-outside) a pay-button and a [donate](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_donate-intro-outside) one.

You will find a lot of info on the [HTML variables PayPal page](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/), too!